# Generating a unique Id for a string using Java

Tags: java, hashcode

I am currently working on a task where I need to append a unique identifier to a string and then create a table in redshift with that name. Currently I was using id.hashcode() to generate the identifier (and my query had create table if not exist) to do the task. But I recently got 1 id for which the generated hashcode is a negative value and Redshift does not allow "-" in the query (Sample name generated : abc-1234).

How can I uniquely identify each incoming Id and if table for that id exists I should not create the table again.

Comment: Please notice that a string's hashcode, besides the fact it may be negative, is not guaranteed to by unique.

Comment: You should use a cryptographic hash, `String.hashCode()` is not intended, nor suitable for this purpose because there is no guarantee it is unique and it allows the full range of `int` as output (as you've noticed).

Comment: What is the range of these strings? min/max length, possible characters, etc

Answer (score 0):

First, any hashcode will be, by definition, less unique than the string itself unless you use any more data to generate it like a timestamp.

You have several possibilities depending on the type of unique identifier that you want to append to the string and how unique you need it to be.

**1ˢᵗ)** A very close to universal unique identifier can be generated **using a timestamp, the machine IP address and a random number** with a method like this one:

```
public String createUniqueKey() {

    int iRnd;
    long lSeed = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Random oRnd = new Random(lSeed);
    String sHex;
    StringBuffer sUUID = new StringBuffer(32);
    byte[] localIPAddr = new byte[4];

    try {

        // 8 characters Code IP address of this machine
        localIPAddr = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getAddress();

        sUUID.append(byteToStr[((int) localIPAddr[0]) & 255]);
        sUUID.append(byteToStr[((int) localIPAddr[1]) & 255]);
        sUUID.append(byteToStr[((int) localIPAddr[2]) & 255]);
        sUUID.append(byteToStr[((int) localIPAddr[3]) & 255]);
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // Use localhost by default
        sUUID.append("7F000000");
    }

    // Append a seed value based on current system date
    sUUID.append(Long.toHexString(lSeed));

    // 6 characters - an incremental sequence
    sUUID.append(Integer.toHexString(iSequence.incrementAndGet()));

    iSequence.compareAndSet(16777000, 1048576);

    do {
        iRnd = oRnd.nextInt();
        if (iRnd>0) iRnd = -iRnd;
        sHex = Integer.toHexString(iRnd);
    } while (0==iRnd);

    // Finally append a random number
    sUUID.append(sHex);

    return sUUID.substring(0, 32);
} // createUniqueKey()
```

**2ⁿᵈ)** You may want to create **a series of keys that increases or decreases over time** so that you can sort on it:

```
private static AtomicInteger iSequence = new AtomicInteger(1048576);

/**
 * Create a universal unique key which increases over time
 * @return String of 32 characters length
 */
public String createTimeDependentKey() {
    char pad[];
    int padLen;
    StringBuilder retval = new StringBuilder(32);
    final long seed = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Random rnd = new Random(seed);
    // 10 characters time dependent part
    String timePart = String.valueOf(Long.MAX_VALUE-seed);
    padLen = timePart.length()-10;
    pad = new char[padLen];
    java.util.Arrays.fill(pad, '0');
    retval.append(pad).append(timePart);
    // 6 characters sequential
    retval.append(Integer.toHexString(iSequence.incrementAndGet()));
    iSequence.compareAndSet(16777000, 1048576);
    // 8 characters IP dependent part       
    try {
        byte[] localIPAddr = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getAddress();
        retval.append(byteToStr[((int) localIPAddr[0]) & 255]);
        retval.append(byteToStr[((int) localIPAddr[1]) & 255]);
        retval.append(byteToStr[((int) localIPAddr[2]) & 255]);
        retval.append(byteToStr[((int) localIPAddr[3]) & 255]);
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        retval.append("7f000000");
    }
    // 8 characters random part
    String randomPart = String.valueOf(rnd.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    padLen = timePart.length()-8;
    retval.append(randomPart).append(generateRandomId(padLen, "0123456789abcdef", Character.LOWERCASE_LETTER));
    return retval.toString();
}

/**
 * Generate a reverse timestamp plus random int identifier of 32 characters length
 * The identifier will be composed of Long.MAX_VALUE-Current Time in Milliseconds followed by a random 32 bits integer
 * @return Numeric identifier of 32 characters length padded with zeros at the left
 */
public String generateReverseTimestampId() {
  String sTs = Str.leftPad(String.valueOf(Long.MAX_VALUE-System.currentTimeMillis()),'0',20);
  String sRd = Str.leftPad(String.valueOf(new Random().nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE)),'0',10);
  return Str.leftPad(sTs+sRd,'0',32);
}
```

3ʳᵈ) You may want to create a pseudo-unique key with only a given set of characters:

```
public String generateRandomId(int iLength, String sCharset, byte byCategory ) throws StringIndexOutOfBoundsException {

  if (iLength<=0) 
    throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException("Uid.generateRandomId() identifier length must be greater than zero");

  if (iLength>4096) 
    throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException("Uid.generateRandomId() identifier length must be less than or equal to 4096");

  if (sCharset!=null) {
    if (sCharset.length()==0) throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException("Uid.generateRandomId() character set length must be greater than zero");
  } else {
    sCharset = "abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz23456789";
  }

if (byCategory!=Character.UNASSIGNED && byCategory!=Character.UPPERCASE_LETTER && byCategory!=Character.LOWERCASE_LETTER)
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Uid.generateRandomId() Character category must be one of {UNASSIGNED, UPPERCASE_LETTER, LOWERCASE_LETTER}");

int iCsLen = sCharset.length();
  StringBuilder oId = new StringBuilder(iLength);
  Random oRnd = new Random();
  for (int i=0; i<iLength; i++){
    char c = sCharset.charAt(oRnd.nextInt(iCsLen));
    if (byCategory==Character.UPPERCASE_LETTER)
      c = Character.toUpperCase(c);
    else if (byCategory==Character.LOWERCASE_LETTER)
      c = Character.toLowerCase(c);
    oId.append(c);
  }
  return oId.toString();
}
```

You´ll also need this array

```
private static String[] byteToStr = {
    "00","01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","0a","0b","0c","0d","0e","0f",
    "10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","1a","1b","1c","1d","1e","1f",
    "20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","2a","2b","2c","2d","2e","2f",
    "30","31","32","33","34","35","36","37","38","39","3a","3b","3c","3d","3e","3f",
    "40","41","42","43","44","45","46","47","48","49","4a","4b","4c","4d","4e","4f",
    "50","51","52","53","54","55","56","57","58","59","5a","5b","5c","5d","5e","5f",
    "60","61","62","63","64","65","66","67","68","69","6a","6b","6c","6d","6e","6f",
    "70","71","72","73","74","75","76","77","78","79","7a","7b","7c","7d","7e","7f",
    "80","81","82","83","84","85","86","87","88","89","8a","8b","8c","8d","8e","8f",
    "90","91","92","93","94","95","96","97","98","99","9a","9b","9c","9d","9e","9f",
    "a0","a1","a2","a3","a4","a5","a6","a7","a8","a9","aa","ab","ac","ad","ae","af",
    "b0","b1","b2","b3","b4","b5","b6","b7","b8","b9","ba","bb","bc","bd","be","bf",
    "c0","c1","c2","c3","c4","c5","c6","c7","c8","c9","ca","cb","cc","cd","ce","cf",
    "d0","d1","d2","d3","d4","d5","d6","d7","d8","d9","da","db","dc","dd","de","df",
    "e0","e1","e2","e3","e4","e5","e6","e7","e8","e9","ea","eb","ec","ed","ee","ef",
    "f0","f1","f2","f3","f4","f5","f6","f7","f8","f9","fa","fb","fc","fd","fe","ff" };
```

A full implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/sergiomt/knowgate-base/blob/master/src/main/java/com/knowgate/stringutils/Uid.java).

Comment: I have the impression that OP wants that the unique ID is always the same for the same string.

Comment: The most unique id that can be generated for a string is the string itself. If the goal is mapping the strings to integers then it's imposible to grant that each distinct string will have its own unique integer (unless the strings are all sort enough).